# Apply jQuery code to divs individually

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code:

```
$('.game-list-right-bottom > .game-list-file').each(function(i) {
  if( i % 4 == 0 ) {
    $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0,4).wrapAll('<div class="game-list-files"></div>');
  }
});
```

to turn this:

```
 <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
  </div>
```

into this:

```
  <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
     <div class="game-list-files">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="game-list-files">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

(basically wrap a `.game-list-files` to every four .game-list-file).

The problem is that I have more than one `.game-list-right-bottom`:

```
  <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
  </div>
```

So it ends up like this:

```
  <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="game-list-right-bottom">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
     <div class="game-list-files">
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
     </div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
        <div class="game-list-file"></div>
  </div>
```

I would like to apply that jQuery code individually to each `.game-list-right-bottom`.
How to archive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  $('.game-list-right-bottom').each(function () {
    $(this).children('.game-list-file').each(function(i) {
      if( i % 4 == 0 ) {
        $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0,4).wrapAll('<div class="game-list-files"></div>');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with using the `.each()` for your `.game-list-right-bottom`, not the childrens.

Comment: I tried this: `$('.game-list-right-bottom').each('.game-list-file').each(function(i) {` but it didn't work.

Comment: What he means is: change it to this: `$('.game-list-right-bottom').each(function() {$(this).find('.game-list-file').each(function(i){..}...}`